# Jira account details not visible in Azure pipeline after configuring the Azure pipelines for Jira app

Tags: azure-devops, jira, azure-pipelines

I have installed Azure Pipelines for Jira app in my Jira software cloud account and added Azure Devops organization in app. Azure Pipelines for Jira app UI is showing my Azure Devops account but when navigate to one of the project's release pipeline page, in my Azure Devops account, 'Jira software cloud account' dropdown is not showing my Jira account information, but it is showing in other project's release pipeline page 'Jira software cloud account' dropdown. I would expect it to be available in all Projects - is this correct ?

[image: release pipeline UI]

Answer (score 0):

Jira connection created through 'Azure Devops for Jira' app is specific to Azure Devops project, not at Azure Devops account level. You can configure for other project through ‘Add Organization’ button in app UI (click ‘Add Organization’ -> select same Azure DevOps account and select other project which you want to configure). Presently ‘Azure Pipelines for Jira’ app UI only showing AzureDevops account information and not showing project information for which projects it configured.